# Multiple client and a server communication

Tags: multithreading, sockets, client-server, command-line-arguments

I am novice to the client server programming, but some how I understood certain things and trying to communicate between client and server. My code is buggy which is not dislaying the entire string, can some one tell me how to send the entire string(which has spaces) to the server from client.

Output:
RHU>> confgiure CM port (this is my entire string)    server reply=configure
RHU>> server reply=CM    RHU>> server reply=port

The above entire thing is output for one string configure CM port

and one more things is there any way to catch these arguments in argv[] with the above case. Here is my server code.

```
//Create socket
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_desc == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}
puts("Socket created");

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

//Bind
if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    //print the error message
    perror("bind failed. Error");
    return 1;
}
puts("bind done");

//Listen
listen(socket_desc , 3);

//Accept and incoming connection
puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);


//Accept and incoming connection
puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
pthread_t thread_id;

while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
{
    puts("Connection accepted");

    if( pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) &client_sock) < 0)
    {
        perror("could not create thread");
        return 1;
    }

    //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
    //pthread_join( thread_id , NULL);
    puts("Handler assigned");
}

if (client_sock < 0)
{
    perror("accept failed");
    return 1;
}

return 0;
```

}

```
//void connectionhandler(void *sock_desc)
{
//write(sock , message , strlen(message));

//message = "Now type something and i shall repeat what you type \n";
//write(sock , message , strlen(message));

//Receive a message from client
while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000, 0)) > 0)
{
    client_message[read_size] = '\0';
    write(sock, client_message, strlen(client_message));
    memset(client_message, 0, 2000);
}

if(read_size == 0)
{
    puts("Client disconnected");
    fflush(stdout);
}
else if(read_size == -1)
{
    perror("recv failed");
}


return 0;
```

}
My client code

```
//Create socket
sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (sock == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}
//puts("Socket created");

server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

//Connect to remote server
if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    perror("connect failed. Error");
    return 1;
}

//puts("Connected\n");
printf("!!Welcome to RHU CLI!!\n"); 
//keep communicating with server
while(1)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("RHU>> : ");  
    scanf("%s" , message);

    //Send some data
    if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }
    //Receive a reply from the server
   if( recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
        break;
    }
    printf("server reply=%s\n", server_reply);
    //if(strcmp(server_reply, "?") == 0)
    //puts("confgiure");
    parse_init(server_reply);
    memset(server_reply, 0, 2000);
    fflush(stdout);
}

close(sock);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Give us some code, the platform you're using, the communication type (TCP? UDP?) and the API...

Comment: joe please review my code that I have posted